# Javascript dependent upon ajax result

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax

I have a table of appointments for a calendar on a page. The table is all the appointments that have not yet been approved.

An admin needs to approve the meetings before they're scheduled, so in the table there is an "Approve" link. Clicking "Approve" calls an ajax method that will set the appointment's 'approved' field to true. The js then removes the row and rebuilds the table so that no full page refresh is needed to see that the appointment is no longer in the table.

My problem is that the ajax method only approves the appointment if there is not already an appointment at that time. If there is a conflict, the appointment should stay unapproved (x.approved = false).

That works fine, but the ajax method just returns a RedirectToAction back to the page with the table and the javascript continues on to remove the row. Upon page refresh, the row returns because the appointment is still unapproved.

Is there a way to return a RedirectToAction and also return a boolean? Is it possible to change a javascript variable (i.e wasApproved) so that the row-removal javascript only runs if (wasApproved == true)? I don't think this is the appropriate time to use ajax's success function because the ajax method should always be successful in running.

Comment: Brando, are you using `asp.net mvc`?

Comment: Yes, sorry. And thanks for the code mark-ups. Forgot to do that

Comment: I don't really get why you are removing the row with javascript.  If you are returning the full table from the action, then that should be the table with or without the row removed?

Comment: When I don't remove the row through javascript it only sets the approved field to true but only disappears from the table after a full page refresh. My Redirect should be refreshing the full page actually.. Is it possible it uses a cached data for the table instead of actually refreshing the entire page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

on your controller, provide a Json result.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Aprove(int id) 
{
    /* process database changes*/
    return Json(new { success = true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And in client side just access with jquery and read this result as a json object. You could remove the line or change redirect to other url as you need. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $("a.aprove").click(function() {
        var id = /* provide an id to pass as a parameter.. could be on the 'rel' property of a tag. */
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: "Controller/Aprove",
          data: { id : id },
          success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) 
                {
                                    // remove the tr row...
                    $(this).closest("tr").remove(); 
                                    // or reload the page with 
                                    // document.location.reload(true);
                }           
          },
          dataType: 'json'
        });         
    });
);
```

Comment: I was actually just now trying this route before I even saw your answer. I think this will end up being the way to go.

Comment: If you want to refresh al page, try to `document.location.read(true)` javascript statment.

Comment: So I've nearly duplicated your javascript and it's not working so I'm thinking it's my controller. I have an if statement saying if there is not a conflict, `app.approved = true;` and `return Json(new { success = true, appId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` So then my else just returns the Json with success = false. Why would that not work?

Comment: are you returning a json object?

Comment: Another thing: it won't let me compile with only those two return statements because it says not all code paths return a value.. Even though it's not an else if. So I put another return statement with `success = false` and I guess that could be the problem. But I thought that if there is no conflict it should get inside the if statement and then return with `success = true`. Then it wouldn't even evaluate the rest of the method, right?

Comment: yes, I return `Json (new { success = true, appId }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: I can't work on this any more today, but I'll be on tomorrow. I'll mark your answer as the accepted answer because it's most likely the way I'll end up achieving my desired results.

Comment: No, when you return an action method, the action on the request stopping execute. If you return a Redirect, Json, FileResult, etc... it just stop executing the request and output the results. If you have success = false, you should provide a message to your users about the error.

Comment: Thanks for the help Felipe! Got it working. For some reason it didn't let me use just my two return statements (for if and else) so I added my original `return RedirectToAction` and it works fine. I debugged it and it never encounters a case where it returns the `RedirectToAction` anyway